# unrecognized rule in lex when using '|' (or) regex

Tags: regex, lex

I'm making a program that identifies keywords, identifiers, int, float and operators with Lex, but I keep getting errors even though there's nothing wrong with it. below is my code. (file name is **d.l**)

In the 6th line, if it is one of several keywords, the keyword is output, so | is used as a regular expression for or.

```
%%
[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,30} printf("identifier\n");
(if|then|else|end|repeat|read|until|write)  printf("keyword\n");
^[-+]?[0-9]*    printf("integer\n");
^[-+]?[0-9]*[.][0-9]*   printf("float\n");
(+|-|*|/) printf("operator");
```

when I execute lex d.l , the result is error message:

```
d.l:6: unrecognized rule
```

I am learning lex and regular expressions for the first time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since line 6 of those shown contains `(+|-|*|/)` and `*` is a Lex metacharacter, you probably need to escape it — `\*` or `'*'` would likely work.

Comment: I think you'll find that `if` is recognized as an identifier. Also, I think that the input `0.123` will be recognized as an integer `0` followed by an unmatchable `.` (and then, maybe, by another integer `123`).  You'll probably need to reorder the rules a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed it to (+|-|\*|/) , but I got the same error.

Comment: Hmmm — come to think of it, isn't `+` another Lex metacharacter too?  Also, I can't see the difference between your amended code in your comment.  (Quote code inside backticks inside comments: `code` is entered as ```…`code`…``` (more or less)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right about the keywords, but the rule for floats should work fine as the float rule will produce the longer match. What confuses me about the number rules is that they only recognize numbers at the beginning of the line, but that looks intentional (why else would the `^` be there?).

Comment: @sepp2k  Integer and real numbers refer to this site. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lex-program-to-accept-a-valid-integer-and-float-value/
 I think I don't even need ^ too

Comment: @user9178840 The `^` represents the beginning of a line, so these rules will only match numbers at the beginning of a line. If you don't want that restriction, you should remove the `^`. To be frank, the geeksforgeeks page is garbage for using `^` without explaining why or what it does.

Comment: @sepp2k — I agree that my comment about the numeric rules was inaccurate.  It's when two rules match the same input string that the order of the rules matters.  Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(+|-|*|/) printf("operator");
```

The problem here isn't your use of `|`, it's your use of `+`, `*` and `/`, which are special characters inside regular expressions (but not inside character classes).

You can fix this by either escaping them (either by prefixing them with a `\` or by surrounding them in quotes) or by using a character class instead, which would be the most idiomatic solution. Note that inside character classes `-` is the one that has a special meaning when it isn't the first or last item in the character class (so don't put the `-` in the middle or escape it).

So either of these solutions will work (with the last one being the most idiomatic):

```
(\+|-|\*|\/) printf("operator");
("+"|-|"*"|"/") printf("operator");
[-+*/] printf("operator");
```

Comment: thanks !! it works. 
(if|then|else|end|repeat|read|until|write) printf("keyword\n");
 There doesn't seem to be any problem here?? I get an error saying that no matching rule was found (in Korean)

Comment: @user9178840 The problem with the keyword rule is the order as Jonathan Leffer already pointed out in a comment. Since the identifier rules comes first and matches the keywords as well, it takes precedence and is always chosen over the keyword rule. I suggest you read up on the maximal munch rule to learn more about when and how the order of rules matters.

Comment: It was hard because I couldn't solve it for a long time, but thank you for letting me know in detail and easily. I'll study it.